# Order Lists in alphabetical order (OrderFilter) with condition that the entries with the values '' were at the end of the list DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Good afternoon Please tell me how to sort the data in alphabetical order in ascending order! But with the condition that the entries with the values "" were at the end of the list. Here is the part of the code that conveys the meaning -

```
    def order_by_custom_fields(self, ordering: list):
        result = []
        field_empty_first = Case(
            When(field__exact='', then=0),
            default=1
        )
        for field in ('field'):
            if field in ordering:
                result.append(field_empty_first)

        return result

    def get_ordering(self, request, queryset, view):
        params = request.query_params.get(self.ordering_param)
        if params:
            fields = [param.strip() for param in params.split(',')]
            ordering = self.remove_invalid_fields(queryset, fields, view, request)
        else:
            ordering = []
        ordering.extend(self.order_by_custom_fields(ordering))
        return tuple(
            self.filters_custom_ordering(ordering)
        )

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)

        if ordering:
            return queryset.order_by(*ordering)

        return queryset
```

This option displays records with '' at the very end, but the order is not alphabetical

But it's necessary

**Update:** Perhaps there is some similar
nulls_last=True for only '' values records? Maybe I misread the documentation looking for this option.
**Update2:** Apparently you will have to change the fields in the database from '' to null